# On what regions is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+|z|}$ (a) continuous, (b) differentiable, (c) continuously differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

On what regions is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+|z|}$ where $z \in \mathbb{C}$ (a) continuous, (b) differentiable, (c) continuously differentiable?

Please provide hint only.  (Only thing I can think of is M-Weierstrass but seems to lead to divergence because of harmonic series).

Comment: You can try with a Leibniz-like test for series.

Comment: @LuisGiraldoGonzalez for what purpose?  show uniform continuity?

Comment: By region of the complex plane, do you mean what is defined in [this article](https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/5337/notes/Chapter1-11.pdf)?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I Just mean for what values $z \in \mathbb{C}$ is the function continuous etc.  I think I managed to show continuously differentiable for $z \in \mathbb{R}$ using the theorem you suggested in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3881427/how-to-show-differentiability-or-not-of-complex-series-but-not-power-series

Comment: Then using the deleted answer below, you can prove that the series is not differentiable in any region of $\mathbb C$ apart from the origin, **providing you mean by region what is meant in the article I linked**.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Sorry How to view the deleted answer?

Comment: As the terms in the series are continuous, by proving uniform convergence you assure the continuity of the sum. As the function depends on the absolute value of $z$ is very likely that the function is not complex differentiable.

Comment: @LuisGiraldoGonzalez Yes that is my issue proving/disproving differentiability on complex numbers.

Comment: @helios321 Can't you see the deleted answer? You posted comments on it.

Comment: Notice that the sum is **always** a real number. Thus, the function cannot be complex differentiable.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net apparently I don't have enough reputation to view deleted answers.  In any case I think the suggestion was to consider the series of $1/n-\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+|z|}$ correct?

Comment: @LuisGiraldoGonzalez Just because the series is always real how can you conclude the function is not differentiable with respect to complex number $z$?

Comment: You can derive that result from the Cauchy-Riemann equations. If the function $f(z) = u(z) + iv(z)$ is real, implies that $v(z)\equiv 0$. But the partial derivatives of $u$ do not need to be $0$.

Comment: @helios321 I reproduced below the response.

Comment: @LuisGiraldoGonzalez So it would then suffice to show that the partials with respect to $x$ and $y$ (where $z=x+iy$) are not identically $0$ for the series?

Comment: It only suffices to show, which is pretty clear, that $f(z) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+|z|}$ is a function from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Then, use the assertion "if a function of a complex variable $z$ is holomorphic and take only real values, then $f$ it must be constant".

Answer (score 0):

**I reproduce here the response from [Kavi Rama Murthy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/142385/kavi-rama-murthy)**. Knowing that this is valid if you use a precise definition of a [region](https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/5337/notes/Chapter1-11.pdf) of $\mathbb C$.

$\sum (-1)^{n} [\frac 1  n-\frac  1 {n+|z|}]=\sum (-1)^{n} \frac {|z|} {n(n+|z|)} $ is uniformly and absolutely convergent on compact sets  since $\sum |(-1)^{n} [\frac 1  n-\frac  1 {n+|z|}]| |z| \leq \frac  {|z|^{2}} {n^{2}}$.

So the sum of the series is a continuous function.

There is no region $D$ in $\mathbb C$  on which the function is differentiable: This function has the form $g(|z|)$. So it is constant on circles with center at $0$. If $z_0 \in D$ then there is an arc of the circle $|z|=|z_0|$ contained in $D$. If a holomorphic function is constant on a set with a limit point then it is a constant on any region containing the set.  This would lead to the contradiction that $\sum (-1)^{n} [\frac 1  n-\frac  1 {n+|z|}]$ is constant in $D$ (I will let you find out why this sum cannot be a constant).

Comment: Thanks.  One more thing , I seem to get that the series continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.  Is this right or wrong?

Comment: Yes, this makes sense as the series of the derivatives is uniformly convergent.