# Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$, what is the derivative of $\frac{1}{a+|z|} $?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$, what is the derivative of $\frac{1}{a+|z|} $?

I am a bit unsure of derivative of complex functions, in particular when is it not the case that you can basically substitute $z$ for a real number?

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(z)=\frac1{a+|z|}$. If $f$ is differentiable at some point $z_0\in\Bbb C$, then so is $\frac1f-1$. But $\frac1{f(z)}-a=|z|$, and $z\mapsto|z|$ is differentiable at no point of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: This is a nice answer. To add, as a remark to the OP, the function $g(z)=\frac{1}{a+|z|^2}$ is differentiable at $z=0$, but not analytic. It's perhaps a good exercise to see why.

Comment: Hi my question was related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3880091/on-what-regions-is-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1nnz-a-continuous can you give some insight on how to determine continuous differentiability?

Comment: Since it is differentiable nowhere, then it is continuously differentiable nowhere.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos But does $\frac{1}{n+|z|}$ not being differentiable necessarily imply that the function defined via the series is also not differentiable?

Comment: There is no series in your question and therefore I don't know what you are talking about here.